# Python for loop using a list

Tags: python

I am trying to search through the list for words containing the variable v. Then when found, print the string containing the variable. At the moment it prints the entire list when the `if` statement is true.

```
v = "g"
word = ["goodbye","goodmorning","foeach"]

for s in word:
    if v in s:
        print(s)
else:
    print("finished")
```

Comment: Please can you clarify? For the code shown, what output are you getting, and what output do you want to get?

Comment: I'm betting you incorrectly copied `print(s)` over, and in your original code you've written `print(word)`

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit: Sounds plausible.

Comment: @kmario23: The code changes in your edit change the meaning of the question. I've reverted the code changes, but left the rest of the edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
print('\n'.join(w for w in word if v in w))
print('finished')
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all: it's just doing exactly the same thing that the OP's code does. The OP has already stated that that code is not giving the desired results.

Comment: Am I misreading the problem? This goes through strings in a list, and prints only those containing `v`, in this case string `'g'`. Upon completion, prints `'finished'`.

Comment: Yep, and that's exactly what the OP's code *already* does. It's clear from the question that that isn't the desired behaviour. Writing an answer that does precisely the same thing using different code (not to mention no explanations) isn't going to help the OP. We need to understand what the OP really wants. Why do you think presenting a generator expression to a self-confessed "total beginner" with no explanations is a useful thing to do?